# How to prevent jQuery UI accordion from opening?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have created a jQuery UI accordion with some additional hyperlinks in its header.
Now when I click one of the hyperlinks in the header the accordion opens up. How can I prevent that? I only want the accordion to open up when user clicks on any space in the header except for the hyperlinks that I added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Want to provide a js fiddle? It'd be very helpful.  Where `.links` is your selector..  Depending on what you want, you'd probably end up with something like this:

```
$(".links").bind("click", function (event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Or a `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation` for more info, check here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/